# How to apply different CSS styles in Rails based on environment?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, environment-variables

In order to easily distinguish between production and staging web site, I would like to apply different CSS styles, based on the Rails environment.

What is the best way to accomplish this please?

Comment: It's a very, very bad way to distinguish prod and staging site. Ideally, your staging server should work in the prod env

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Can you please elaborate, why it is a bad practice?

Comment: Staging is commonly used to pre-check app functionality before deploy to prod. You can't be completely sure that your css works well if it differs on staging and prod

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rails.env.production? and add some class to div, body etc...
If you want to do it global in you application layout add something like:

```
<!-- application_layout -->
<body class="<%= Rails.env.production? ? 'prod-class' : 'dev-class' %>">
</body>
```

If is only for some div or element:

```
<div class="<%= Rails.env.production? ? 'prod-class' : 'dev-class' %>">
</div>
```

Comment: Or you can use `Rails.env.staging?` in the same way

Comment: Thank you, that helped.